# Why are websites suddenly not secure?

Tags: firefox, security, https

Firefox updated today, without asking me. The update went well, and browsing works fine, with one exception- Websites are suddenly not providing any identity credentials. DeviantART, Lumosity, Facebook, EBay, and even Superuser are suddenly not providing this information.

This is especially worrying because some of these websites (pretty much all of the ones listed above) have personal and important information, such as my credit card information.

According to Firefox, Google was giving these credentials at first, but after a few seconds of being on Google, it switched back to not having these credentials, somehow. More worrying is that the same happens with PayPal. Am I at risk for any of my information being stolen? And how can I reverse this, or is it that websites are just not giving this information and I can't do anything about it?

I initially assumed that this is a problem with my browser and that it just wasn't pulling identity information even if it was provided, but contrary to my theory, firefox IS actually pulling this data- seemingly from only a small amount of sites.

Please pardon my poor grammar and spelling, as it is quite late and I am rather tired.

Comment: What does it say if you manually enter a **https://** address e.g. https://www.google.com ? What happens in other browsers?

Comment: Same thing happens with other browsers- They aren't secure.  If I enter HTTPS:// and then the address, it removes the HTTPS:// and continues to load the page as it did before without the security credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If it's multiple sites, I'd assume it's malware, or the system time is incorrect. The time is easiest to check first. If the time is good, do a malware scan with 2 different products. I recommend malware bytes anti malware and avg

Comment: System Time is correct and AVG didn't detect anything (I have had AVG for a while now)

Comment: Try the other one too. Different scanners detect different malware